# android where to create application data directories

Tags: java, android

I am an iOS programmer and trying to migrate an app to Android. I need to create application directories to handle some files. iOS has reserved a folder for each app called documents directory but where is used to create directories to handle data on android? SD card, flash or root? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want isolated private data storage? That's labelled as "internal storage" for Android apps. Check out this [page.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for the `assets` folder.
This folder is reserved for raw files that are **NOT** under the Resource Control of the AndroidOS. If you need ResourceControl by Android you should check out the `res` folder.